# Dynamic Where filter through navigation Property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a generic Where filter that works great so far (only interested in `Contains` filters):

```
private static MethodInfo contains = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetFilter<T>(string propertyName, string value)
{
    var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
    var member = Expression.Property(item, propertyName);
    var constant = Expression.Constant(value);
    var body = Expression.Call(member, contains, constant);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, item);
}
```

Is there any way I could extend this so that I could search by a navigation property? I'm very new to using `Expression` so I'm not sure what to try.

An example would be:

```
public class A
{
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

dbContext.As
    .Where(GetFilter<A>("B.Name", "Hello World"))
    .ToList();
```

But this fails on `Expression.Property("B.Name")` with:

> Instance property `B.Name` is not defined for type `A`

Comment: You'll gain all the knowledge you need from https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/blob/master/Src/System.Linq.Dynamic/DynamicLinq.cs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create each member access sequentially for each property in the property path :

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetFilter<T>(string propertyName, string value)
{
    var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");

    Expression member = item;
    foreach (var prop in propertyName.Split('.'))
    {
        member = Expression.Property(member, prop);
    }

    var constant = Expression.Constant(value);
    var body = Expression.Call(member, contains, constant);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, item);
}
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto glad to help  :) Don't forget to mark as answered :)